# Mozilla PDF.js Name of file in printing dialogs

Tags: javascript, php, printing, mozilla, pdf.js

Please someone can help me, how to set a name of file in printing dialog of browser?

I use Mozilla PDF.js version v3.5.141

PDF files is send to default viewer.html as base64.

I can change title in browser with function, after creating objects:

`setTimeout(() => { // Wait for PDFViewerApplication object to exist PDFViewerApplication.setTitleUsingUrl(name_of_pdf_file); }, 1000);`

Thats work fine.

But when user click on print button, and for example change print to PDF, then always default name is:

"PDF.js viewer.pdf"

Many thx for advice for all

Comment: Doesn't happen for me, when I use the first example under https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js#online-demo, press the "print" icon, and select "save as PDF" in Chrome - the suggested file name is `compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf`, same as the window title showed before. Can you clarify in what situation / under what circumstances you experience the problem?

Comment: Yes, in this case is ok. But I sent PDF file as base64 hash and then use variable DEFAULT_URL = hash. After that by function setTitleUsingUrl i set Title of PDF in browser

Comment: Maybe this can help then, https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/10435#issuecomment-452706770

Comment: Many thx for advice, but i dont use this function (PDFViewerApplication.open) for opening decode PDF file... 
I use way of overload DEFAULT_URL variable.  Maybe I must change this